Stripe webhooks not firing (live mode) - randomly stopped working, I didnt change anything
First things first to avoid being asked redundant questions:
My code and webhooks are set up perfectly fine for live mode. My webhook secret and api keys are all in live mode and everything worked. However, things have stopped working randomly and events are no longer firing.
I then change the webhook secret and api keys to test mode and test mode was working and detecting the events.
Im listening for customer.subscriptions.update and customer.subscriptions.deleted
Also when i was on live mode if from the dashboard i resent an event it would work in my code and the stripe webhook function in my code would run. It just no longer detects webhooks automatically..
Any ideas how to fix this? I literall haven't changed anything it just stopped working I even tried on  different server and still didnt work.I created new webhook, still didnt work.
Edit: My workaround was just listening to other events such as invoice.paid since that also detects payments in the form of checkouts and recurring charges and and subscription id is part of the object. Thank God for this workaround! Also customer.subscription.deleted works its just updated that stopped firing, maybe there's been a change in API or update that's gone wrong but now i'm using invoice.paid instead, i think it may be more reliable as well. I hope this helps anyone else who intially has working webhooks and then they randomly stop. Just try to see if you can listen to alternative events and then get a bit creative to try and replicate the desired behaviour.
